# Optional array in struct

Tags: go

I want to make an array optional in struct and use it with an if else in a func.

```
type TestValues struct {
    Test1 string `json:"test1"`
    DefaultTests []string `json:"__tests"`

    //DefaultTests *array `json:"__tests,omitempty" validate:"option"`
    Test2 string `json:"__Test2"`
}
```

```
func (x *Controller) createTest(context *gin.Context, uniqueId string, testBody *TestValues) (*http.Response, error) {

    if testBody.DefaultTags {
        postBody, err := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
            "Test2":              testBody.Test2,
            "Test1":                  testBody.Test1,
            "defaultTests":         testBody.DefaultTests,
            "uniqueId":                  uniqueId,
        })
    } else {
        postBody, err := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
            "Test2":              testBody.Test2,
            "Test1":                  testBody.Test1,
            "uniqueId":                  uniqueId,
        })
    }

    ...
}
```

When I run the code it tells me that DefaultTests is undefined array but I don't want this error to pop because DefaultTests can existe and sometimes it won't be present in the json that's why I want  to make it optional. The if else part is not working too.

Comment: What is`DefaultTags` in `if testBody.DefaultTags` and why are you checking it? It must be something of type `bool` or else you will see a compiler error. And where/when does this "undefined array" error pop up? Include the *exact* error in your question and explain.

Comment: Use a pointer to indicate missing in JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use [len()](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#len) when checking if an array is empty here.

```
if len(testBody.DefaultTests) > 0 {
  ...
}
```

Check the Zero value of the DefaultTests in struct below for more clarity on this behaviour

```
package main

import "fmt"

type TestValues struct {
    Test1        string   `json:"test1"`
    DefaultTests []string `json:"__tests"`

    //DefaultTests *array `json:"__tests,omitempty" validate:"option"`
    Test2 string `json:"__Test2"`
}

func main() {
    var tv = TestValues{Test1: "test"}

    if len(tv.DefaultTests) > 0 {
        fmt.Printf("Default Tests: %v\n", tv.DefaultTests)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Default Tests empty value: %v\n", tv.DefaultTests)
    }
}
```

Comment: but what if DefaultTests doesn't exist all together in the json ? how to check for that ?

Comment: when I created the object here ```var tv = TestValues{Test1: "test"}``` I didn't add any DefaultTests.. but still you can see the output as [], which means when DefaultTests doesn't exist it's set to [] (which is what we call zero value in Go)

Comment: you should ideally be able to check with ```tv.DefaultTests == nil``` as well.

Comment: @MarcSimon generally you should not base your reasoning on the output of the `fmt` package. A `nil` slice is not the same as an empty slice, yet `fmt` displays them identically.

Comment: @BenDou Go is a statically typed language. When you define a struct with N fields, then an instance of that struct will have **always** N fields. The number of the fields is static. It doesn't dynamically change just because one or more fields weren't *initialized*. When you don't initialize a field explicitly it will be initialized automatically by the runtime to the zero value of the field's type. The zero value of a slice type is a `nil` slice.

Comment: @BenDou Therefore, to check whether a field was initialized or not you can compare it against the zero value, which in the case of slice fields is `nil`. And if you want to exclude initialized but empty slices you can use the builtin `len` function, which returns `0` for both `nil` slices and non-nil but empty slices. https://go.dev/play/p/KdmTtmaPvv_v

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final code with Marc's answer

```
func (x *Controller) createTest(context *gin.Context, uniqueId string, testBody *TestValues) (*http.Response, error) {

if len(testBody.DefaultTags) > 0 {
  postBody, err := json.Marshal(testBody.DefaultTags)

} else {
    postBody, err := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
        "Test2":              testBody.Test2,
        "Test1":                  testBody.Test1,
        "uniqueId":                  uniqueId,
    })
}

...
```

}